# Namespace notation in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've just cloned the [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/) [repo](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/), and my goal would be to hack one of the [examples](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/tree/master/tutorial).
I've starting by moving one of the tutorials in a different folder. However each CMakeLists.txt looks like the following:

```
get_filename_component(PROJECT_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin igl::core igl::opengl igl::opengl_glfw tutorials)
```

I'm not an expert in CMake but I've never seen syntax like `igl::core igl::opengl igl::opengl_glfw`,

Can anyone tell me what that means? Is it like a namespace in C++? The [toplevel CMake](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) is a project named `libigl` so it must be related somehow.

Comment: Partially because I'd like to know what exactly happens in relation to libigl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0028.html):

> The use of **double-colons** is a common pattern used to namespace
>   IMPORTED targets and ALIAS targets. When computing the link
>   dependencies of a target, the name of each dependency could either be
>   a target, or a file on disk. Previously, if a target was not found
>   with a matching name, the name was considered to refer to a file on
>   disk. This can lead to confusing error messages if there is a typo in
>   what should be a target name.

Furthermore, from [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-packages.7.html?highlight=namespace):

> A **NAMESPACE** with double-colons is specified when exporting the
>   targets for installation. This convention of double-colons gives CMake
>   a hint that the name is an IMPORTED target when it is used by
>   downstreams with the target_link_libraries() command. This way, CMake
>   can issue a diagnostic if the package providing it has not yet been
>   found.

So the namespaces can be used as in the following CMake snippet:

```
export(EXPORT ClimbingStatsTargets
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ClimbingStats/ClimbingStatsTargets.cmake"
  NAMESPACE Upstream::
)
```

Comment: How does this map to the `libigl` project?

Comment: @user8469759 it doesn't map to the `libigl` project only but to every other project... Here is just explained the use of double colons

Comment: Am I right when I say the double-colons denotes an alias in this context? It seems from the doc the colons itself doesn't mean anything, it's just a pattern commonly used. Also If I'm right does this mean I should see this alias declared or imported somewhere?

Comment: @user8469759 check updated answer

Comment: I'll carefully read through your answer.

Comment: Stupid question, if I wanted to use the namespace outside that folder structure how would I need to setup my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @user8469759 you can take a look at [this](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) blog article here